# lightning web component Inline Editing datatable for Multiple Rows issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I have inline edit datatable component for a opportunity related object. I am facing an Error when i click 1st click and clicking multple clicks records are updating. 
Error message is "unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records"

```
  <template if:true={bookings}>
                    <lightning-datatable
                            key-field="Id"
                            data={bookings}
                            columns={columns}
                            hide-checkbox-column="true"
                            show-row-number-column="false"
                            onsave={handleSave}
                            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                            draft-values={draftValues}>
                    </lightning-datatable>
                </template>
```

---

```
handleSave(event) {
        const recordInputs =  event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });
        console.log('recordInputs*****'+recordInputs);
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        console.log('promises*****'+promises);
        Promise.all(promises).then(bookings => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Bookings updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            // Clear all draft values
            this.draftValues = [];

            // Display fresh data in the datatable
            this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('### error ' + JSON.stringify(error.body));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Bookings error occurred on save ' + error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: As per the documentation ----> updateRecord(recordInput, clientOptions) expects a single record only. So you must pass in a recordInput object for each record whose fields you are updating.


So does that mean UpdateRecord() function will update single record at a time.

Comment: Can anyone help me on the issue..?

Comment: Can any help me the issue?   Is UpdateRecord() function will update single record at a time??